# Why is there no .gz file in my unity build?

Tags: unity-game-engine, webgl

In my unity build(2020.3.22f1), I am running it inside of WebGL. I get this error when I try to run it.      [This is the error shown.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wy1yH.png)

Any Help?

Comment: Did you upload all the folder structure and files? Did you configure your webserver as instructed by unity as it is not default

Answer (score 0):

If your binary-files do not end up with ".gz" the compression format in your publishing setting might not be GZIP.